# Milnor-Stasheff Characteristic Classes Problem 7B, Borel 1953

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cohomology, characteristic-classes

There is the following Proposition 11.1 from Borel's 1953 paper *La cohomologie mod 2 de certains espaces homogènes* (see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564561)).

> **Proposition 11.1** The classes $w^i$ and $\overline{w}^j$ are related by$$\sum_{i + j = k} w^i \overline{w}^j = 0 \quad (k = 1, 2, \dots),$$and each of the systems $H(\textbf{G}_{m, n})$ multiplicatively.

You may recall this as the following question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229736/cohomology-algebra-generated-by-n-steifel-whitney-classes-and-and-k-dual-cla) asked on MO a few days ago. I don't see at all how why this is true. Could anybody explain? I've talked to a few math graduate students today and none of them have any idea as to why this is true, so I do not think this question is at too low of a level for MO.

Comment: "I've talked to a few math graduate students today and none of them have any idea as to why this is true, so I do not think this question is at too low of a level for MO." I do not think this the correct rationale (I am not saying I think this question is too low level).

Comment: Maybe you can try this: assuming $n \leq k$, by Problem 6-C,E and contents in section 6, we know $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ has the same k-skeleton as $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$. You can show $w_i$ and $\bar w_i$ are nontrivial by constructing Cartesian product of n or k copies of tautological line bundle over $P^1$ and use cellular approximation on the defining map to the infinite Grassmannians. The relation is obvious, since they are S-W classes for tautological bundle and its complement.

Comment: To show they are the only relation, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ cellular chain maps are all $0$ by the knowledge of infinite Grassmannian and this is a subcomplex. Then the defining relations give you a way of counting $\mathbb{Z}/2$ ranks of cohomology group in each dimension, and you only need to prove they are equal to number of cells in each dimension. I didn't check this part but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @MingcongZeng Sorry I'm still confused, like are you saying explicitly find the ranks of cohomology directly from the cellular cochain complex, and show that it is equal to the ranks implied by that one relation, so no other relations hold? That's the only way it makes sense to me, but it doesn't seem computationally feasible.

Comment: It's a proposition, isn't it proved in the paper?

Comment: Can't you apply the Whitney sum formula to a bundle and it's complement (so that the direct sum is a trivial bundle) ?

This would be the very first thing I would try simply based on the statement of the problem. I guess you have already tried this then, so what goes wrong?

Comment: As Fernando says: there's literally a proof of the result *in the link you provide* to Borel's paper.

Comment: @FernandoMuro The proof in the paper seems "inefficient" on some level and I do not really understand it, I'm wondering if there is a nice solution given the machinery that has been developed in Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: @Student The method proposed by Sean to prove the relation works. Are you asking why the Stiefel-Whitney classes generate the cohomology of the grassmannian? In that case I would suggest to go by induction on the dimension. I'm sure it is done somewhere in Milnor-Stasheff.